# Sublime text 3 (Latextools) wont show PDF

Tags: sublime-text, build-system

Been a while since I used Latex so I decided to give ST3 a try since it has become my favorite text editor.

I installed the Latextools but upon building it won't show my PDF. The build is fine as I get these messages:

> Output written on `test.pdf` (1 page, 83250 bytes). Transcript written
>   on test.log. [Finished in 1.4s]

The PDF is also updated correctly but it simply won't show it. I checked the readme me on Latextools and it says this.

> On Windows, both MikTeX and TeXlive are supported. You must be running
>   a current (>=1.4) version of the Sumatra PDF previewer. Install these
>   as usual; then, add the SumatraPDF directory to your PATH (this
>   requirement will be removed at some point)

This just confuses me. Do I need to install Sumatra PDF? I always just use Adobe Reader?

Comment: Adobe Reader / Acrobat is not that great to use during writing, because it locks the file. So you have to close the pdf every time before you compile it, and open it again afterwards. You don't have to do that with sumatra, it just shows the updated pdf after complation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think i used TexShop (on my imac and TexWorks) in the past. So i guess i can install Sumatra PDF. 

What do they mean with add the directory to my path?